# ERROR: Parameter 8 was incorrect on entry to ZHEEV

Tags: fortran, lapack

```
module RandMat
    implicit none
    double complex, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A, L, U
    integer :: n

    contains
    function Diag() result(Eigenvalues)
            implicit none
            double complex, dimension(n) :: Eigenvalues
            double complex, dimension(2*n-1) :: work
            double precision, dimension(n,n) :: eigenmatrix
            integer :: Lwork
            integer :: info, ii
            double precision :: rwork(3*n-2)
            double complex :: check(n,n), alpha, beta


            check=A
            info=0
            lwork =2*n-1
            !call routine to diagonalize A
            call zheev('V','U',n, check, n, Eigenvalues, work, lwork, rwork, info )


   end function
end module
```

This function is declared within a module. `A` is a `n x n` Hermitian matrix that I defined within the module, so I can use it in here. `n` is defined in the module as well and is the dimension of `A`.

The problem is that I always get a run time error:

```
    Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 8 was incorrect on entry to ZHEEV
```

when calling `zheev`.

EDIT: I added the declaration of the variables in the module. The Matrix A is allocated and initialized with the following Routine:

```
    subroutine Initialize
            implicit none
            integer, dimension(2) :: clock
            integer , dimension(:), allocatable :: seed
            integer :: ii,jj
            double precision :: c,d


            !create random complex matrix of dimension nxn
            !-----------------------------------------------------------------------
            !allocate A
            if (.not.allocated(A))  then
                    allocate(A(N,N))
            else if (size(A,1).neqv.N) then
                    allocate(A(N,N))
            end if
            !get execution time--> will be used as seed
            call System_clock(count=clock(1))
            call random_seed(put=clock)
            !initialize matrix with random values
            do ii=1,n
                    !since we are only interested in hermitian matrices is it enough to only                                !initialize the upper diagonal matrix
                    do jj=ii,n
                            call random_number(c)
                            Call random_number(d)
                            A(ii,jj)=cmplx(c, d)
                    end do
            end do
            !make matrix hermitian
            !---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            do ii=2, n
                    do jj=1, ii-1
                            A(ii,jj)=conjg(A(jj,ii))
                    end do
            end do
    end subroutine
```

Comment: I don't see the declaration of `n` or `A` in the module but I assume you did it correctly. It would be much cleaner to pass it as an argument and avoid global variables. Parameter `8` is `LWORK`, but `2*n-1` should be fine.

Comment: A typical way of raising this error is to supply a 32 bit default integer argument but link the ilp64 libraries which requires int64.  The details you omitted are important.

Comment: The details tim18 was asking for are something else. We need to see the commands you are using to compile and link the program and to see how you are using the LAPACK library in those commands.

Comment: It would also be nice to see where you set n - the use of subprogram arguments is so much clearer. Oh, and also your initialise routine does not create a Hermitian matrix as the diagonal elements will have a complex part when they should be purely real.